# Open mobile app (if installed) using javascript (without intent)

Tags: javascript, android, ios

From web browser, I want the ability to open any app if installed (such as facebook, twitter etc) using java-script. I can't update intent file, want to do it solely from java-script. Is there a way from java-script to detect the installed apps (from IOS & Android) and open it?

Comment: the app has to be set up to open the url in their app. if you click on a link to a google maps url in android you are given teh option to open it in the app, not because of any javascript, but because the app is registered to open those kind of links.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Firebase Dynamic Links https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links

It was designed to resolve the issues like yours.